# Unsubscribing from Observable in a non-Component/Directive class

Tags: angular, memory-management, rxjs, observable, subscription

I've read tons of posts on unsubscribing from `Observable`s in Angular and all of them mention the need to do so in components/directives only.

So my question is:

Do we need to unsubscribe from `Observable`s in a non-component/directive class e.g. in a service or basically any other class that contains subscriptions to `Observable`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You unsubscribe in components because when you remove them from DOM (eg. with `*ngIf` or whatever) RxJS chains would hold references to observers you created there. Thus introducing memory leaks.

In general you don't have to unsubscribe in services because they exist during the entire lifetime of your application.

However, in Angular you can create a component that for example provides a different service instance only to its descendants (this means you might have multiple instances of the same service class in your app). In such case you should unsubscribe manually (probably when destroying the component that defined them).

Comment: So in short, we could set a rule: we must unsubscribe in **any** cases whenever a subscription is supposed to live shorter than **infinite** `Observable`. Subscriptions in components/directives are just most common cases of that. Is it true?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Yes, that's basically the rule I follow.

Comment: Usually it would be best to unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy of the service when doing it manually. If a service is provided by a component that is then destroyed (an no other components are referencing that service, the service will be destroyed and then its on destroy function will be called.

Comment: Also, for components/services that are never destroyed for the life of the app, be watch out for the case of unit tests, where those components might be destroyed. In that case you either still need your unsubscribes in the component/service, or you need to clean those subscriptions up in an after test hook in your test runner.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to call out why unsubscribing is important. It's never necessary to unsubscribe from a stream, but there can be advantages to performance and in some cases it's important to unsubscribe as part of the feature.

It's also important to say that unsubscribing is the responsibility of the consumer. The only way for a stream to "force" a consumer to unsubscribe is by completing or erroring.

In Angular services, if you end up subscribing to a stream, unsubscribing is good practice unless you have a good reason to keep listening. Here's an (contrived) example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor( private session: Session ) { }

  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {

    return Observable.create( observer => {
      const innerSubscription = this.session.subscribe( session => {
        if ( session.user.isLoggedIn ) {
          observer.next( true );
        }
        observer.next( false );
      });

      return function unsubscribe() {
        innerSubscription.unsubscribe(); // this "cleans up" our subscription.
      };
    });

  }
}
```

There are other, better, ways to write this code, it's just an example. So in this case, we have a non Component/Directive that subscribes to a session. Every time the session changes, we look to see if the user is logged in and notify our listeners if they are/aren't. If everyone unsubscribes from *us*, we would still be listening to `this.session` unless we (the service) explicitly unsubscribe.